# Python desenhar na tela

Tags: python, interface, tela

Alguém sabe se tem algum método que eu possa desenhar na tela pura? Sem o uso de uma janela de interface gráfica, vou dar um exemplo pra entenderem melhor

(Ignorem pra onde está apontando) a questão é, tem alguma maneira de desenhar na tela sem janelas? Tipo desenhar igual na imagem
[image: .]

Comment: Tem que fazer chamadas especificas nas APIs gráficas de cada sistema operacional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo de como desenhar diretamente no desktop usando a chamadas da Win32 API [MoveToEx()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-movetoex) e [LineTo()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-lineto)

```
import win32api
import win32gui

#Pega o contexto gráfico para o Desktop
dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)

#Desenha uma linha do ponto (0,0) até (1366,768)
win32gui.MoveToEx(dc,0,0)
win32gui.LineTo(dc,1366,768)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Você tem que usar uma biblioteca que tenha as funcionalidades de desenho - e que faça a intermediação com o sistema operacional.

Para "deixar a tela preta" e você poder desenhar tudo do zero, um das mais fáceis de usar em Python é o [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news). (Para instalar o pygame, em geral só é necessário digitar `pip install pygame` na linha de comando (cmd no windows)

Para desenhar na janela "raiz" do sistema operacional, onde ficam o background e os ícones, é possível - mas não usual - usando-se bibliotecas como Qt, ou a API direta do sistema operacional (Xlib no Linux) - e mesmo que o sistema te autorize, o que você desenhar estás sujeito a ser apagado de repente em qualquer redesenho da tela.

Com pygame, para se desenhar na tela inteira, basta chamar o setup de janela passando o indicador `pygame.FULLSCREEN` como segundo parâmetro. É importante lembrar de chamar `pygame.quit()` numa construção do tipo `try ...finally` , senão, se o seu programa der algum erro enquanto está em tela cheia, você pode ficar "preso" na tela gráfica.

Exemplo mínimo para apagar a tela, preenche-la com a cor branca, desenhar um retângulo vermelho, esperar alguns segundos e terminar:

```py
import time
import pygame


def main():
    try:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (50,50,300,200)) 
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(5)
    finally:
        pygame.quit()


main()
```

Note que eu uso a resolução "1024, 768" - que é meio que "universal" - você pode fazer o pygame imprimir (com print mesmo) a saíd de `pygame.display.list_modes()` para saber as resoluções nativas disponíveis na sua máquina.

No mais, a própria documentação do pygame em https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html  e na página de "events" pode te ajudar a criar desenhos mais elaborados e interagir com o teclado e o mouse.